# Why can't I select the first rows data range from a pivot table from another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

The sheet with the pivot table is named `Pivot` and the pivot table is named `PivotTable3`:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3")

Worksheets("Pivot").Activate
pt.PivotFields("Row Labels").DataRange.Select
Selection.Copy
```

I thought this would select the first row for me. However I am met with error "1004".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what range you want. Try one of those:

```
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").TableRange1.Rows(1)
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").TableRange2.Rows(1)
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataBodyRange.Rows(1)
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").RowRange.Rows(1)
```

Or maybe something like  `Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").TableRange1, Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataBodyRange.Rows(1).EntireRow)`

BTW, the following approach is to be banned (and actually, all people with experience on VBA will avoid it):

```
SomeSheet.Activate
MyRange.Select
Selection.DoSomeAction
```

Instead, simply do `MyRange.DoSomeAction`.

This will be smoother with no blink on the screen.